# Cannot acquire data source [java:app/projectName]

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, glassfish, persistence

I am new at JPA , I use Glassfish 4.1.1, when I try to create an `EntityManagerFactory` it shows this Exception message:

> javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-7060]
>   (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150605-31e8258):
>   org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException Exception
>   Description: Cannot acquire data source [java:app/quiz]. Internal
>   Exception: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for
>   'java:app/quiz' in
>   SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory,
>   java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl,
>   java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root
>   exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: No object bound to
>   name java:app/quiz]

I checked my configurations files, and I think they are correct, can anyone help me?

**Persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="QuizPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>java:app/quiz</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**glassfish-ressources.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE resources PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Resource Definitions//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-resources_1_5.dtd">
<resources>
    <jdbc-connection-pool allow-non-component-callers="false" associate-with-thread="false" connection-creation-retry-attempts="0" connection-creation-retry-interval-in-seconds="10" connection-leak-reclaim="false" connection-leak-timeout-in-seconds="0" connection-validation-method="auto-commit" datasource-classname="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource" fail-all-connections="false" idle-timeout-in-seconds="300" is-connection-validation-required="false" is-isolation-level-guaranteed="true" lazy-connection-association="false" lazy-connection-enlistment="false" match-connections="false" max-connection-usage-count="0" max-pool-size="32" max-wait-time-in-millis="60000" name="mysql_quiz_rootPool" non-transactional-connections="false" pool-resize-quantity="2" res-type="javax.sql.DataSource" statement-timeout-in-seconds="-1" steady-pool-size="8" validate-atmost-once-period-in-seconds="0" wrap-jdbc-objects="false">
        <property name="serverName" value="localhost"/>
        <property name="portNumber" value="3306"/>
        <property name="databaseName" value="quiz"/>
        <property name="User" value="root"/>
        <property name="Password" value=""/>
        <property name="URL" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/quiz?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"/>
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    </jdbc-connection-pool>
    <jdbc-resource enabled="true" jndi-name="java:app/jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/quiz" object-type="user" pool-name="mysql_quiz_rootPool"/>
</resources>
```

Comment: Try `mysql_quiz_rootPool` instead of `java:app/quiz` ?

Comment: do you mean like this ? 
<jta-data-source>mysql_quiz_rootPool</jta-data-source>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, I added this code to the web.xml file and it works fine

```
<resource-ref>
 <res-ref-name>java:app/quiz</res-ref-name>
 <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
 <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
 <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>
```